# Powershell Windows Form Border Color / Controls?

Tags: forms, powershell

Is there a way to set the border color Red on focus and then back to none when focus is lost?
I'd also like to set the border style thicker at the same time if possible.

```
$form= New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text= "Testing"
$form.StartPosition= 'CenterScreen'
$form.ClientSize= '400,200'
$form.text= "Form"
$form.BackColor= "#0077f7"
$form.TopMost= $true
$form.AutoScroll= $true
$form.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") { $form.Close() } }) # if escape, exit
$form.KeyPreview= $True

$lbl_one= New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lbl_one.text= "Input"
$lbl_one.AutoSize= $true
$lbl_one.width= 25
$lbl_one.height= 10
$lbl_one.location= New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$lbl_one.Font= 'Verdana,12'
$lbl_one.ForeColor= "#fafa00"

$txt_one= New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txt_one.TabIndex= 1
$txt_one.multiline= $false
$txt_one.text= "test1"
$txt_one.width= 100
$txt_one.height= 20
$txt_one.location= New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,10)
$txt_one.Font= 'Verdana ,12'
$txt_one.ForeColor= "#0077f7"
$txt_one.Add_GotFocus({ $txt_one.BackColor="LightBlue" } )
$txt_one.Add_LostFocus( { $txt_one.BackColor="White" } )

$lbl_two= New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lbl_two.text= "Input"
$lbl_two.AutoSize= $true
$lbl_two.width= 25
$lbl_two.height= 10
$lbl_two.location= New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$lbl_two.Font= 'Verdana,12'
$lbl_two.ForeColor= "#fafa00"

$txt_two= New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txt_two.TabIndex= 1
$txt_two.multiline= $false
$txt_two.text= "test2"
$txt_two.width= 100
$txt_two.height= 20
$txt_two.location= New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,40)
$txt_two.Font= 'Verdana ,12'
$txt_two.ForeColor= "#0077f7"
$txt_two.Add_GotFocus({ $txt_two.BackColor="LightBlue" } )
$txt_two.Add_LostFocus( { $txt_two.BackColor="White" } )

$form.controls.AddRange(@($lbl_one,$txt_one,$lbl_two,$txt_two))
[void]$form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be cludgy, but you can try adding this helper function on top of the code:

```
function Paint-FocusBorder([System.Windows.Forms.Control]$control) {
    # get the parent control (usually the form itself)
    $parent = $control.Parent
    $parent.Refresh()
    if ($control.Focused) {
        $control.BackColor = "LightBlue"
        $pen = [System.Drawing.Pen]::new('Red', 2)
    }
    else {
        $control.BackColor = "White"
        $pen = [System.Drawing.Pen]::new($parent.BackColor, 2)
    }
    $rect = [System.Drawing.Rectangle]::new($control.Location, $control.Size)
    $rect.Inflate(1,1)
    $parent.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle($pen, $rect)
}
```

and set up the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` event handlers like this:

```
$txt_one.Add_GotFocus({ Paint-FocusBorder $this })
$txt_one.Add_LostFocus({ Paint-FocusBorder $this })
...
$txt_two.Add_GotFocus({ Paint-FocusBorder $this })
$txt_two.Add_LostFocus({ Paint-FocusBorder $this })
```

and at the very end of the code:

```
# call the Paint-FocusBorder when the form is first drawn
$form.Add_Shown({Paint-FocusBorder $txt_one})

# show the form
[void]$form.ShowDialog()

# clean-up
$form.Dispose()
```

P.S. Inside an event handler scriptblock, you can refer to the control itself using the `$this` [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#this).

Also, do a `$form.Dispose()` when done with it.

Comment: Thank you [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo).  When I tested though, I have to roll tab through both fields at least once before the red border shows up.  Suggestion for fixing that?

Also, is there a good website you recommend for how to do Windows forms with PowerShell?  Google doesn't show much for PowerShell.  

Thank you again!

Comment: @PaulWasserman I have edited my answer to make the code more generic and to draw the border when the form is first shown. A good site for building forms with PowerShell is [POSHGUI](https://poshgui.com/)

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I did use POSHGUI to create my initial page, and wondered what website you would use for the windows form controls, especially related to Powershell.  Thanks again Theo!

Comment: Follow up question - This is working perfectly in Powershell 5.1, but fails in Powershell 7.

PS C:\work> .\formsTest.ps1
SetValueInvocationException: C:\work\formsTest.ps1:6
Line |
   6 |  $form.ClientSize= '400,200'
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception setting "ClientSize": "Cannot convert the "400,200" value of type "System.String" to type
     | "System.Drawing.Size"."


...

Comment: @PaulWasserman I think you could simply remove the quotes, so you give it two int values, or try `$form.ClientSize = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(400,200)`

Comment: Found my answer.  For Powershell 7, we have to use defined values rather than just the values.  
    $form.ClientSize = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(400,200)    

    $blue = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(0,120,250)  

    $lightblue = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(173,216,230)  

    $white = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255)  

    $red = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,0,0)  

    $verdana = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label  

    $verdana.font = (new-object System.Drawing.Font('Verdana',12,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold))

Comment: This is great! Thank you!