# How to display a mouseover textbox tooltip in Windows Forms PowerShell?

Tags: winforms, powershell, textbox, tooltip, mousehover

Can someone show me an example of how to add a mouse hover tool tip to a textbox on a Powershell windows form? Thanks for your help!

Apologies for not posting my code directly in here, but I keep getting an error each time before I submit.

Code can be found here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u7r_vaMh8sEsAWsXLcFtxfAXtYTcURj2/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429550/powershell-windows-form-border-color-controls) about the same project, I would recommend adding yet another helper function to handle both textbox controls:

```
function Show-ToolTip {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [System.Windows.Forms.Control]$control,
        [string]$text = $null,
        [int]$duration = 1000
    )
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($text)) { $text = $control.Tag }
    $pos = [System.Drawing.Point]::new($control.Right, $control.Top)
    $obj_tt.Show($text,$form, $pos, $duration)
}
```

I would also suggest storing a default text for the tooltip in the `Tag` property for each textbox. You can always change that dynamically in the MouseEnter events:

```
$txt_one.Tag = "Testing my new tooltip on first textbox"
$txt_two.Tag = "Testing my new tooltip on second textbox"
```

Next, add the event handlers for these boxes:

```
# event handlers for the text boxes
$txt_one.Add_GotFocus({ Paint-FocusBorder $this })
$txt_one.Add_LostFocus({ Paint-FocusBorder $this })
$txt_one.Add_MouseEnter({ Show-ToolTip $this })   # you can play with the other parameters -text and -duration
$txt_one.Add_MouseLeave({ $obj_tt.Hide($form) })

$txt_two.Add_GotFocus({ Paint-FocusBorder $this })
$txt_two.Add_LostFocus({ Paint-FocusBorder $this })
$txt_two.Add_MouseEnter({ Show-ToolTip $this })
$txt_two.Add_MouseLeave({ $obj_tt.Hide($form) })
```

and below the `[void]$form.ShowDialog()` dispose of the tooltip object too:

```
# clean-up
$obj_tt.Dispose()
$form.Dispose()
```

P.S. During testing, I found that using the `MouseHover` event did strange things when showing the tooltip.. Every now and then, the arrow was pointing upwards, away from the textbox. Changing to `MouseEnter` accompanied by `MouseLeave` worked best for me.

---

As per your comment, I cannot test in PS 7, but for me in PS 5.1 it works:

[image]

---

Thanks to [Paul Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10481803/paul-wasserman), who found out there should be a registry setting under
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\`
by name of `EnableBalloonTips`.
It is a DWORD value that needs to be set to `1`. If your machine is missing that registry value, or it is set to `0`, **NO Balloon-style ToolTips will show up**.

Comment: Theo, thank you again for your help.  I've tried running this in various versions of PowerShell (5&7), and I never see the tooltip popup (see video)
Video - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jYd1pTg_lfOdG9fO7hog1ysqjr8UA1IM/view?usp=sharing
Updated Code - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u7r_vaMh8sEsAWsXLcFtxfAXtYTcURj2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @PaulWasserman I cannot test in PS 7, but for me in PS 5.1 it works like you can see in the image I've added.

Comment: I copied the script from my windows 10 machine to my windows 2019 server, and the tooltips worked!  Now I will have to investigate why.  You are awesome Theo!

Comment: @PaulWasserman Sorry I don't have all these different windows's to test on.. I'm on Win10 Pro v 1909 btw.

Comment: Same for me, Windows 10 Pro 1909.  My Powershell version on my Windows 10 machine is 5.1.18362.752.  On the windows 2019 server, I'm running a slightly older version 5.1.17763.1007.

Comment: @PaulWasserman Weird, we have the same OS and also the exact same PS version 5.1.18362.752. Just a shot in the dark, but what if you try the [overloaded constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8) for the tooltip: `$obj_tt = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip $form.Container` ?

Comment: Found it... it was a windows 10 registry setting.  Under Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\   there needs to be a DWORD entry for EnableBalloonTips with the value set to 1.  Mine was set to 0.  Once I changed the value and then restarted Powershell, it worked.  And it worked in both PS5 and PS7!  Thank you again @Theo for all your help :-)

Comment: @PaulWasserman Good find! Glad to hear there was a solution to this.

Comment: @PaulWasserman I have added this useful information to the answer, so others can benefit.